# framework to call javascript functions from code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

Some time ago(1 month or so) I saw a framework and one of its main features was the ability to call javascript functions from code behind, my hard drive died on me a week ago so I lost the bookmark, can someone tell me the name of that framework or another one with that feature?

As I want to keep my code clean and avoid the use of RegisterClientScriptBlock or ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript, those are evil...

EDIT: It's a 3rd party framework, so nothing with Microsoft frameworks

I wanna use the framework along with Backbone.js and its listeners feature, so I can send a JSON object to a js function and it will update my html templates easily

Comment: Why is `ClientScript` _evil_? Could you be more specific as to what you are trying to do? You can't call javascript from code behind directly. You can only inject javascript into the page that will call other javascript functions.

Comment: Depends on how you use them but I've seen things like this ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyKey", "alert('" + strResponse + "');", true);

And my code buddies are used to write JS in the code behind, instead of write the functions in .js files, let's say its a matter of organization...

Comment: Any tool can be abused, but that's the correct way of injecting javascript from code behind.

Answer (score 0):

just use 
asp.net ajax
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act.ashx

Comment: I've used the toolkit before, but not my taste, thanks for your prompt answer.